# Converting imageview pixels to bitmap pixels after gesture

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-canvas

I have an imageview, I want to convert the touch event on the image to its corresponding pixel on the orginal bitmap (even after the image has been gesture scaled or flinged).

How can this be achieved?
Thanks

Comment: by using `Matrix` API - get It by calling `ImageView#getImageMatrix()`

Comment: @pskink that's exactly what I am having trouble with. If I use some library that scale or zoom image, and then get the click x and y Cordinates. How can map these coordinates to the original image view as if it was not scaled or zoom. This was I can map the results to the original bitmap

Comment: you have the `Matrix`? if not, there is no way to map the point as you dont know the scale/translation/rotation

Comment: Would imageview.getimagematrix get me the matrix you are referring to? Or should I go to the library source and keep track of the matrix that had scale and zoom applied to?

Comment: what library do you mean? is it a custom `ImageView`?

Comment: I can use either photoview library or zoomage. Essentially they are custom imageview.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a code example of how to determine the x and y of image view after it has been zoomed and translated? Maybe if I can see the code I would be able to undertand it and take it from there (or at least get it to the state where your code would integrate)

Comment: ok so what's unclear in Matrix API methods?

Comment: I know how to use matrix to do translate and rotate and zoom . I am just not sure what I need to do to figure out where the click would correspond to in order to map it to the orginal bitmap

Comment: and what `Matrix` method did you try to use in order to map your touch point?